# Memory support on mbd asrock Z370M pro 4

Tags: memory, cpu

So, I've been looking for additional memory for my PC (CPU:i5 8400). In mbd guide book is written *8th gen intel CPU supports DDR4 up to 2666. Is this patched somehow or the limit is still 2666 for 8th gen? (I'm asking bcs this mbd supports I9 9900 now, which didn't exist in the time I have built my PC)

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not prohibited from installing a better specced compatible ram.
It will just run at the lowest speed that all the other hardware is compatible with. So if you're not planning on overclocking or upgrading the cpu - it's not rational to pay a premium for the speed that will not be used.
Higher speed memory usually used to run more stable at lower speeds, but again - with modern ram and no overclocking you will not notice.